# Ubuntu Software Installed section

Tags: 20.04

1) I have recently installed Ubuntu 20 LTS. I went to the Ubuntu Software app and clicked on installed. This section is completely blank. There is an error message that states that the app can't find the directory.

2) I downloaded the Ubuntu Studio software installer and installed all the software on top of regular Ubuntu. I want to remove some of this software but I am unable due to the problem above.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will help, but please check below link which has a similar kind of question that you asked:

[Software Center Not Showing Installed Apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230644/software-center-not-showing-installed-apps)

For some people, it fixed the issue but for some, it didn't.