# Software Center Not Showing Installed Apps

Tags: software-center

Just upgraded to 20.04. At first the software center was working fine. I could scroll down and look at the categories. I could click on the installed tab and see the installed apps. A few hours after later the installed tab is just blank. Today, I can't scroll down to the categories. Is this just a bug that will get fixed soon or should I reinstall it? If so, how do I reinstall it?

Comment: The package name is `gnome-software`. So try `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software`.

Comment: I just tried it and the categories in the explore tab are still missing and the installed tab is still empty. Thanks though.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue.
There was a conflict with the snap store.
Running `killall snap-store` in a terminal then relaunching the app fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me, using Ubuntu 201.10

Comment: This worked for me, thanks

Comment: worked fine in my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 5):

Restart your PC!

Same problem after fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, there are no categories in the software center.

What I did: opened the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), then

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software
```

I tried to open software center, still the same. Then, restarted my machine and voilà:

[image]

I don't know if it is worth mention but I think in the beta version software center was fine. I don't remember having problems.

Comment: I did restart my machine after reinstalling it earlier and still had the problem. But I tried it again and now the categories are back. Though the installed tab still shows nothing. Thanks though.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Restarted twice, went to Intalled tab & after the spinning circle stopped, nothing.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a conflict in the Software Center.

What helped me is opening a terminal and running:

```
killall snap-store
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I first used the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-software
```

followed by a new

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```

Works for now...