# Ubuntu Software doesn't show installed softwares

Tags: gnome, 20.04, software-center

The Ubuntu Software doesn't show the installed softwares:

[image]

Today I installed also sudo apt install gnome-software and it showed installed softwares. After I checked if there was updates for Ubuntu, I installed them and, after the reboot, also gnome-software doesn't show installed softwares.

How could I get the installed softwares list in Ubuntu Software or in Software (i.e. gnome-software)?

---

EDIT1: if I install a new software from Ubuntu Software, I can see it in Installed window, but, after reboot, it disappears.

---

EDIT2: I don't want to use terminal.

Answer (score 1):

## Install `synaptic`

The Ubuntu Software (Center) does not list all software available in repositories or installed. This is particularly true for command-line utilities. Another GUI alternative to Ubuntu Software is `synaptic` also known as **Synaptic Package Manager**. You should be able to find in in Ubuntu Software. If not, install using the following command:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

## Open `synaptic`

Open `synaptic` as you usually open any GUI software. It will prompt you to enter your password before it opens.

On the left panel you can select **Installed** to see all the installed software in your system:

[image]

The green squares indicate that a software is installed. If you want to see if a specific software, such as `gnome-software` is installed, click on the big search button and type the name of the software. You can limit the search to just **Names** or **Names and Description** (if you want to search for a keyword, rather than the exact name). You will get something like this:

[image]

As you can see above `gnome-software` and `gnome-software-common`are installed and other packages with similar names are not installed, as they don't have the green square next to them.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello @user68186 I upvoted your answer because it's an alternative way to see "what I want"...but this is not what I'm lookin for. I know that I can see the list of installed software in the software center because I saw them only one time in my life and then it disapear. See the paragraph "Bonus Tip: Show installed applications in Software Center" please https://itsfoss.com/list-installed-packages-ubuntu/#12:~:text=Bonus%20Tip%3A%20Show%20installed%20applications%20in%20Software%20Center

Comment: ...moreover if I search a software (e.g. okular) the synaptic shows me okular and a list of packages related to okular, instead the ubuntu software center shows me only okular without all the strange packages

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Thanks for the detailed comments and the upvote. I don't have a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since gnome-software/ubuntu-software isn't showing your installed apps you should try listing your installed apps in Terminal!

Just type this command in the terminal "apt list --installed"

Hope this has helped!

:D

EDIT 1a: Please note that this command shows more than what gnome-software/ubuntu-software shows! There may be filters for this command but I don't know!

Comment: @user68186 You can post that as an answer :D

Comment: How about `apt list --installed gnome-software` to see if `gnome-software` is installed?

Comment: @user68186 he has gnome-software installed

Comment: The last commant was in response to your EDIT at the bottom of the answer. :D

Comment: I will write about `synaptic` in an answer.

Comment: Hello @JaydenW. I know the above terminal command, but I'd like to avoid terminal.

Comment: Please refer to the fallowing articles:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230644/software-center-not-showing-installed-apps

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, programs disappeared from Ubuntu software center after I interrupted the Ubuntu system update. Then the problem was fixed after running in terminal:
sudo dpkg --configure -a